# grep SHA-1 hash with possible prefix

Tags: regex, bash, git, grep

I want to grep from `git submodule status <PATH>` the SHA-1 commit hash of my submodule. According to `git submodule --help`:

> status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [...]
>
> Show the status of the submodules. This will print the SHA-1 of the currently checked out commit for each
>              submodule, along with the submodule path and the output of git describe for the SHA-1. Each SHA-1 will
>              possibly be prefixed with - if the submodule is not initialized, + if the currently checked out submodule
>              commit does not match the SHA-1 found in the index of the containing repository and U if the submodule has
>              merge conflicts.

So the result looks something like this:

```
 f1eeb6aa2a5009b5ef68b5b754499dcb3ab575d1 my-submodule (remotes/origin/HEAD)
```

The description mentions that each hash will be possibly prefixed with a `+` or a `-`. I'm not interested in the signs, and therefore, for whatever result it gives me, I want to get the 40 character hash without the prefix.

Example:

```
input: +f1eeb6aa2a5009b5ef68b5b754499dcb3ab575d1 my-submodule (remotes/origin/HEAD)
desired output: f1eeb6aa2a5009b5ef68b5b754499dcb3ab575d1

input: f1eeb6aa2a5009b5ef68b5b754499dcb3ab575d1 my-submodule (remotes/origin/HEAD)
desired output: f1eeb6aa2a5009b5ef68b5b754499dcb3ab575d1
```

I've tried something like `awk '{print $1;}' | grep -e '[0-9a-f]\{40\}'` but it doesn't seem to remove the prefix. Any elegant solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to grep from `git submodule status <PATH>` the SHA-1 commit hash of my submodule.

Why go through the gyrations? Just ask for what you want directly:

```
git rev-parse :<PATH>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add option `-o` to your grep command.

> `-o`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line

Answer (score 1):

You can use the output of [`git ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree):

Instead of:

```
D:\git\git>git ls-tree master -- sha1collisiondetection
160000 commit 855827c583bc30645ba427885caa40c5b81764d2  sha1collisiondetection
```

You would get:

```
git ls-tree master -- sha1collisiondetection|awk "{print $3}"
855827c583bc30645ba427885caa40c5b81764d2
```